columns by default in agenda view (what's wrong with my elisp?)
Admittedly my elisp is pretty bad, but for the life of me I can't understand what's going on here. AFAIK the first example below should display the agenda view in column view by default, but it doesn't.
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands '(
                                   ("z" "important" (
                                                     (tags "IMPORTANT" (
                                                                        (org-agenda-overriding-header "important")
                                                                        (org-agenda-view-columns-initially t)
                                                                        ))
                                                     )
                                    )
                                   ))

If I remove 2 sets of brackets it works.
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands '(
                                   ("z" "important" 
                                                     tags "IMPORTANT" (
                                                                        (org-agenda-overriding-header "important")
                                                                        (org-agenda-view-columns-initially t)
                                                                        ))
                                   ))

My understanding is that the working example isn't good code. How should I be writing this elisp properly?

One minor nit-picking thing: what do you mean by "code"? In most languages, there is a distinction between "code" (the stuff you run) and "data" (the stuff that the code manipulates). In Lisp, the distinction is much less visible: they are both lists. But you cannot eval an arbitrary list and conversely, a list representing data must conform to the structure that the code that manipulates it expects. In particular, org-agenda-custom-commands is a data structure and it has to conform to the specification that is described in its doc string. The answer explains this well.

Thanks pointing this out - I appreciate the importance of accurate nomenclature. In this case would it have been better to say "My understanding is the working example isn't good elisp?" (I understand from elyuku's answer that there was nothing wrong however)

Just the formatting - which BTW Emacs can help you with it: see Editing programs in the Emacs manual. "Good elisp" is generic enough to cover anything. I just wanted to point out the distinction in this case, because sometimes people have the wrong idea about what is code and what is data. But I didn't mean to worry you about it too much. It's just background info.

I'd thought the formatting looked off, but this was the formatting suggested when I entered the elisp in my scratch buffer in emacs-lisp-mode. elisp doesn't look like this in my dotfile. I'll read up on your suggested link and see if I can't figure out where I went wrong.

See also Emacs Lisp Coding Conventions - there a couple near the end that are particularly relevant.

Your elisp looks fine to me (except the placement of the linebreaks that make the indentation look awkward). If you check the documentation of org-agenda-custom-commands with describe-variable, it says "Each entry is a list like this: (key desc type match settings files)", where only settings is a list. So your second version is indeed how it's supposed to look like:
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
      '(("z" "important" 
         tags "IMPORTANT"
         ((org-agenda-overriding-header "important")
          (org-agenda-view-columns-initially t)))))

Then it says "You can also define a set of commands, to create a composite agenda buffer. In this case, an entry looks like this: (key desc (cmd1 cmd2 ...) general-settings-for-whole-set files)", and I guess this is where you got the parentheses around tags from. In this case, it seems that the problem is that org-agenda-view-columns-initially does not work as a command-specific setting (those inside the same parentheses as tags), but only as "general-settings-for-whole-set files". For example, this works for me:
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
      '(("z" "important"
         ((tags "IMPORTANT" ((org-agenda-overriding-header "important")))
          (agenda "" ((org-agenda-overriding-header "Agenda"))))
         ((org-agenda-view-columns-initially t)))))

